# @staticmethod or function outside class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Assuming I have a `class` which requires a function (or should I say method) which is:

- independent from my `class` instance - doesn't need `self` argument;
- is called only inside my `class` object
- I won't need access to it at any point (to override it for example);

should I (A) place it inside the `class` and mark it as a `@staticmethod` or should I (B) define it outside my `class` object (but in the same namespace)? Why?

Example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, my_int):
        self.my_int = my_int
    def my_int_and_4(self):
        print(self.adder(self.my_int,4))
    @staticmethod
    def adder(a,b):
        return a+b
```

or

```
def adder(a,b):
    return a+b
class B:
    def __init__(self, my_int):
        self.my_int = my_int
    def my_int_and_4(self):
        print(adder(self.my_int,4))
```

EDIT: maybe the example is a bit oversimplified. I should have added that my version of "`adder`" is specificly used with my `class` and in no other case.

Comment: Given your three conditions I would put it inside the class (where it doesn't clutter the module's namespace).  The second condition is the one that would incline me in that direction.

Comment: It depends on how specific it is for your class. I know you said it wont be called anywhere else at the moment, but that condition can change. Especially if you find yourself implementing the same function privately elsewhere. I'm guessing `adder` is an overly simplified example, which is obviously generally applicable, but if its more rooted to a single class, it may server better as a class method. At the end of the day, it wont be hard to switch from one to the other if you need to so don't agonize over it too much.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a textbook use case for a private static method.

They key point here is that you should make it a private method of that class.  That way you're certain nothing else will use it and depend on its implementation.  You'll be free to change it in the future, or even delete it, without breaking anything outside that class.

And yeah, make it static, because you can.

In Python, there is no way to make a method truly private, but by convention, prefixing the method name by a `_` means it should be treated as private.

```
    @staticmethod
    def _adder(a,b):  ## <-- note the _
        return a+b
```

If at some point you suddenly need to use it outside the class, then exposing it will be no trouble at all, e.g. using a public wrapper method.

The reverse, however, isn't true; once exposed, it's difficult to retract that exposure.

Comment: Great answer, but why did you use name mangling? He said it wouldn't be overriden.

Comment: Are the `__` mandatory or would also just `def adder(a, b)` work?

Comment: Python does not have private methods. The double underscore prefix provides name mangling which is supposed to be useful in multi inheritance scenarios with conflicting attribute names. Just prefix it with a single underscore, if nobody else should touch it.

Comment: If you don't *need* name mangling, you should probably just use a single underscore (which is private by convention). Name mangling makes things harder to debug, and if you ever decide you do need to access the attribute or method from somewhere outside the class, it makes it much more awkward (you either need to rename the method everywhere or have the external caller use the mangled name `_A__adder`, which is really ugly).

Comment: Points well taken, changed to single `_`. @Cleb: Sure, it will still work without the `_`, but then you're not signaling that it's intended to be private.

Comment: `... then exposing it will be no trouble at all, e.g. using a public wrapper method` What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: @Cleb `def adder(a,b): 
return self._adder(a,b)`? Or if that's too lazy for you, just refactor that one class, renaming `_adder()` to `adder()`

Answer (score 3):

I would definitely use a private static method in this case, for the reasons described by Jean-Francois Corbett. There are two types of methods in Python that belong to the class itself, rather than an instance: class methods and static methods.

The first parameter of a class method (created with `@classmethod`) references the class in exactly the same manner that the first parameter of an instance method (`self`) references an instance. It is the equivalent of static methods in most other languages. If your method requires access to other class members, use a class method.

A static method (created with `@staticmethod`) does not contain a reference to the class, and therefore cannot reference other class members. It's generally used for private helper methods and the like.

For your `adder` method, I would definitely use a static method. However, in this modified (and rather useless) version, a class method is necessary:

```
class A:
    x = 1
    def __init__(self, my_int):
        self.my_int = my_int
    def my_int_and_4(self):
        print(self._adder(self.my_int,4))
    @staticmethod
    def _adder(a,b):
        return a+b
    @classmethod
    def _increment(cls, n):
        return n + cls.x
```

Comment: `my_int_and_4()` method call leads to an error: `AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'adder'`. It should be `self._adder(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

Both approaches will work, so it's the matter of readability and following conventions.

- Does the method need to look at the instance's private attributes? If yes, it's a good reason to keep it in the class.
- Is the method only used as a helper for one of different methods? If yes, it's a good reason to put it right after the calling method so that the code can be read top-down.
- Does the method seem to make sense outside of the context of your class? If yes, it's a good reason to make it a free function or even move it to a different file, like utils.